# What pre-requisite knowledge is required for developing android apps, Iphone etc?

Tags: new-operator, prerequisites

I am looking forward to start a mobile application development business and wish a to have direct knowledge of the technologies that run behind the cool apps. Being new to the programming / development world...pls suggest if it is better to learn .Net or Java before learning about Android SDK, iOS SDK etc?

Comment: I dont know much about it, but what would .Net have to do with Android?

Answer (score 1):

well if your goal is android development you should learn java. if you want to do windows phone 7 .net would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response John!!

Comment: I would wishto extend my business to iphone app development as well...is java still a better option? is it recommended or absolutely necessary to have a prior knowledge?

Comment: iphone is objective c, completely different skillset to android/windows phone.

Comment: Thanks RPM1984...PLs suggest skill sets required for Objective C ?

Comment: you should think of a simiple application and then try to program it.  If you try to troubleshoot the problems you have when programming you'll discover that learning come as you figure out your problems.

Comment: if you have a "newer" mac with leopard you can get xcode for free and use the simulator without testing on a device.  Before submitting an app to the app store you need to have a paid account ($100) and you should do testing on a real device, emulator != device.